# Is there any coding style guideline for Optional.ifPresentOrElse?

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type

I wrote a piece of code that looked like this:

```java
propertySupplier.getSomeProperty().ifPresentOrElse(
    property -> //do something with the property,
    () -> log.error("property not found")
)
```

and I showed it to my supervisor. He didn't like it and told me he'd rather have something like this:

```java
Property someProperty = propertySupplier.getSomeProperty();

if(property == null) {
    log.error("property not found")
} else {
    //do something with the property
}
```

The reason for this being that he wants to know as soon as possible what a function is going to do (fail early). This is understandable but I don't agree on introducing the `null`. So I was wondering if there is a code style guideline yet for how to make this functional notation easier to read that I can show him? To clarify I am not asking for opinions, I know that's frowned upon here, but merely for resources to read or show that I could not find myself.

Comment: `propertySupplier.getSomeProperty()` return an Optional?

Comment: @YCF_L yes it does, I wasn't sure how to show that here but I figured my use of ifPresentOrElse implied that :)

Comment: You want to throw an exception if the value is null?

Comment: I think your supervisor might be a bit new to using Optional.

Comment: yes I think so too ;)

Comment: @YCF_L possibly I haven't gotten to that point yet, might be enough to just log it.

Comment: In this case, I would to follow the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something for the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Your version is better. However I thinks the following satisfies both:

```
Property property = propertySupplier.getSomeProperty()
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                    log.error("property not found");
                    return new NoSuchElementException();
                });
```

Comment: I would to use `propertySupplier.getSomeProperty()
        .map(property -> /*so something*/)
        .orElseThrow(() -> {
            log.error("property not found");
            return new NoSuchElementException();
        });`

Comment: @YCF_L some variants possible. For a design decision it is better to offer something simple. `Property property = propertySupplier.getSomeProperty().orElseThrow();` (since java 10) would even be a good starting point for fail-fast.

Comment: the log + exception is a nice touch